# Using die() to return ajax value in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Are there any reasons to not to use `die($result)` to return Ajax request result in PHP? Please note that this is theoretical question, about code semantics.

Simple example (of course functions may be much complicated and return different values).

JS:

```
<script>
   function checkLogin(login){
      $.post('/ajax/check',{'login':login},function(res){
          if(res == 1) return 1; else return 0;
      }
   }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
   $db = mysql_connect(...);
   $login = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['login']));
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project.users WHERE login = '$login'");
   if(mysql_num_rows($res)) die('0'); else die('1');
?>
```

PS. I know tha that `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated, no need to comment that. I simply like using them and will. As far as it will be possible.

EDIT:

I wonder why noone noticed that `checkLogin()` function has no sense, as request is async, and function always returns `undefined` ;-)

Comment: Mostly a matter of preference i'd say. However, does your code here actually work? `die(1)` would set a exit code, not actually output a `1`

Comment: @hank Good point. edited.

Comment: BTW I liked the attitude `mysql_*() functions are deprecated, no need to comment that`

Comment: Someone marked the question to close as opinion based. I don't ask about opinion, but about problems that may appear. If I would know what kind of problems may appear, I wouldn't ask the question. And hank have proven, that this question is useful. Wouldn't notice that error myself.

Comment: i think that res is type String use 

if (res == '1')

Comment: I'm a one man band coder... so I can live with conventions I am aware of, of which this could fall into that category. If used in wrong context by a team though could lead to bigger headaches. Thus it sounds like ( from reading responses) best practice would be avoid it. Learned a bit reading this post though....including Flash likes his `mysql_` methods!

Comment: @charlietfl I am lone wolf too. As a new technology development director in quite big company, there are two main types of projects: the ones that I don't believe my crew can manage (I'm doing those myself, and noone is allowed to touch them) and others - that I don't touch.

Answer (score 2):

Since `die()` does not send any `HTTP` error status, there is no problem using it to return a string for an ajax call, but what stays there to say is, for the readability of the code, I don't think it's a good idea, but other than that, for functionality, there is no problem with it,since it outputs the message.
but also, now that's it's said, you have to take into consideration cases like `CLI PHP` in which the returned integer can really mean something for the shell(just for mentioning).

Comment: I don't agree about readability. It's like returning from function. Of course, there are some cases when it is not a good idea, but for simple ajax functions, seems to be better than echo(); die(); or creating some variable to return it at the end, when we don't need anything else to do. But `+1` of course.

Comment: you're totally write if the page has simple functionality to run, but what I was saying is totally general.

Comment: This is a good answer in terms of content, but it is very hard to read due to your lack of sentence breaks. It would upvote it if it were more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that no, you don't want to do this. It is not made to return something to an ajax call, it is an equivalent to `exit()`, and you can give it a status.

That is just opinion though, but one that does have to do with semantics: it isn't meant to be used as a sort of `echo`, so don't use it as one.

The fact that you can have it 'return' an integer (as in, that works), but if you'd put in 255 it will not because it is reserved makes it tricky and unreadable.

So sure, while syntactically it works for values like `'0'`, it would consider it bad form to use a language structure to return arbitrary messages, as it cannot return all messages.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by `return all messages`. From JS point of view, there is no difference in `echo 1;` and `echo '1';`.

Comment: I meant the same as some of the others said :). Your example is great: you wouldn't expect a difference when doing `echo 1` or `echo '1'`, and you wouldn't expect the same when 'returning' your value with `die` or `exit`. But there _is_ a difference between `die(1)` and `die('1')` and there's the point where it is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a problem. In your too simple case no, but imagine this:

```
die($Result);
```

How will that behave? **You don't know what that will do**, since you don't know the type of $Code. As *hank* pointed out, if it's an integer it won't print anything. So you have a line of code that will behave differently depending of `$Result`. It seems very prone to [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

PHP documentation:

```
    Note: PHP >= 4.2.0 does NOT print the status if it is an integer.
```

A better solution would be to improve the control of the flow:

```
if ($this_is_NOT_an_ajax_call) {
  // Do what you need to do
  }
else {
  echo $Result;
  }
```

Comment: ad1. This could be the problem, but doesn't have to be, as you can simply use `die("$result");`

Comment: Or you can use `die(strval($result))` and I'm sure there are more methods. But `die("$result");` is still more prone to errors that `echo $result;`. Another point would be if you work with other people/other people needs to maintain your code.