# cannot set return value in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to web technologies and trying to build up through examples .This question seems to be recurring. However, I am unable to get the correct syntax/method.

I am attempting to read the value set by an ajax call (action.php) and use it on client side (js). Below is my attempt

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/crm/action.php",
        data: form,
        success:  function(data){
            alert(data.error);          
        },
        error: function () {
            myalert("DATABASE ERROR","X Record not saved. if this error persists, contact your system administrator");
          }
      });
```

And action.php simply tries to set the variable "error" as below

```
 $error = 1;
```

All my attempts have returned "undefined" so far.

Comment: console.log(data) returns anything?

Comment: do you return the variable or only set it? set the alert to console.log and use data instead of data.error to check if anything is present

Comment: I would like to return the variable. For test purposes  $error = 1  is the only statement in php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your action.php to the following:

```
die(json_encode(['error' => 1]));
```

Make sure there isn't anything else outputted but the above.

Comment: Rather than `die()`, simply use `echo json_encode(['error' => 1])`. Also the OP is new perhaps it's better to tell that he needs PHP version >=5.4 for `[]` shorthand array syntax to work.

Comment: the variable $error is generic.I would like to understand how to return any variable from server side process

Comment: die(json_encode(['I_want_that_name' => $anyVariableIHave]));

then in your javascript:

success:  function(data) {
            alert(data.I_want_that_name);          
        },

Comment: `die()` prevents further execution of the script. This might not be desired always. And asking a new user to use `die()` instead of helping him understand why response is not returned is mis-leading. Also see [Using die() to return ajax value in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757177/using-die-to-return-ajax-value-in-php)

Comment: I have tried the method suggested, the ajax calls returns with an internal server error. is there any files to include? Is the syntax for the ajax call correct?

Comment: @user2810718 that means your php is as Samundra suggests <5.4 and you have to define arrays the old way, so the code should be:
echo json_encode(array('error' => 1));

Comment: still getting undefined as the value.  What i think, it may have to do with asynchronous behaviour. at the time of alert the ajax call has not eturned any vale yet...just a thought

Comment: @user2810718, nope the success() is called when server returns the response and the response code is 20x.

Comment: @jakub wrona yes it was a matter of syntax. After havong struggles so long with..i started doubting the most basic principles of hiw call backs work